# Determine what the type of typedef is

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I want to use something for positive infinity. However, the data type my code uses is typedef'ed by other people's class. That means that it can an int, a float, a double and pretty much numerical types.

Previously when I used infinity, I would something like `INT_MAX` for integers and so on. However, can I determine (at **compile**) the type I am using?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488612/how-can-i-write-a-method-to-determine-the-typedef-type-at-runtime) answer, but I don't think it's what I am looking for.

But on the other hand I can't think of an elegant method to achieve this.

In code:

```
typedef float FT;

// in another file
//if FT is int
int inf = INT_MAX;

...

//if FT is float
float inf = FLOAT_MAX;
```

But still, this would not be nice, because then I want to pass it as a parameter to a function. What would be the signature of the function is the first problem that comes to mind.

[EDIT]

The signature could use the typedef.

Comment: "At run time" doesn't make sense. I think you mean "at compile time" (as opposed to "at preprocessing time").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could check out [`numeric_limits<T>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/).

```
// numeric_limits example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <limits>       // std::numeric_limits

typedef float FT;

int main () {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "Minimum value for FT: " << std::numeric_limits<FT>::min() << '\n';
  std::cout << "Maximum value for FT: " << std::numeric_limits<FT>::max() << '\n';
  std::cout << "FT is signed: " << std::numeric_limits<FT>::is_signed << '\n';
  std::cout << "Non-sign bits in FT: " << std::numeric_limits<FT>::digits << '\n';
  std::cout << "FT has infinity: " << std::numeric_limits<FT>::has_infinity << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

With `typedef float FT;`

```
Minimum value for FT: 1.17549e-38
Maximum value for FT: 3.40282e+38
FT is signed: true
Non-sign bits in FT: 24
FT has infinity: true
```

With `typedef int FT;`

```
Minimum value for FT: -2147483648
Maximum value for FT: 2147483647
FT is signed: true
Non-sign bits in FT: 31
FT has infinity: false
```

Comment: Or just `typedef std::numeric_limits<float> NL`.

Answer (score 3):

You can query the type at run-time using the [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator.  However, this won't solve your problem. If all you want is the most positive number a type can hold, use [`std::numeric_limits<FT>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max). Note that there is also [`std::numeric_limits<FT>::has_quiet_NaN()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_quiet_NaN). These are compile-time `constexpr`essions, which is what makes them really useful.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to accept the other answer, because it came first. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename enable_if_helper = void>
struct get_infinity_helper;

template <typename T>
struct get_infinity_helper<T, typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity>::type>
{
    static constexpr T infinity = std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity();
};

template <typename T>
struct get_infinity_helper<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity>::type>
{
    static constexpr T infinity = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
};
```

Then use `get_infinity_helper<T>::infinity`.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to accept the first answer, because it came... first. ;p